# How can I determine the Linux distro in vimscript?

Tags: vimscript

In shell I do conditional stuff depending on distro like this:

```
eval "$(source /etc/os-release && typeset -p ID)"
if [[ $ID =~ ^(rhel|fedora.*|amzn|ol|rocky|almalinux)$ ]]; then
  ...
fi
```

How could I do that in vimscript?

Comment: Using source that way seems like it could open you to attacks. But in Vim you could read the lines of the file (readfile()) and find the one with ID (filter ()), then grab everything after the = (matchstr?)

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I've started using different terminal colours on different machines/servers to help me know where I am and wanted to change the vim colourschemes to match. I can't think of a better way to differentiate as they all use the same dotfiles. I could use hostnames, but this would not need updating.

Comment: @paradroid ah okay that makes sense. I would in that case use as on the suggested answer `readfile()` or `system()` or `systemlist()` to get the distribuation. But note, checking this on startup, may slow down your startup time (obviously)

Comment: From your answer, what you need isn't determining the distro but the term (or some of its available capabilities.) What I mean is that within the same distro the results may differ according to the installed packages and account settings.

Comment: @gildux No, it isn't about the `$TERM`. It is determining the distro or being able to make settings depending on it.

Answer (score 3):

As I pointed out in my comment, I suspect it's an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). I wouldn't read any files in `/etc` in Vim at all. Although I have to say I'm delighted to have read some great answers.

A comment on the question says the same dotfiles are used on all machines and I think that's where things start to go wrong. Those are configuration files, they are meant to be *configured*. So allow for some system-specific tweaking.

I would propose a distro-agnostic approach of reading from an optional, machine-specific configuration file like this:

```vim
" set defaults that make sense
" ...
if filereadable(expand('~/.vim/overrides/distro.vim'))
    source ~/.vim/overrides/distro.vim
endif
```

You can put the config file next to your Vim configuration like in my example or specify another path. See `:help filereadable()` and `:help expand()` for usage information.

There are two more points to consider which largely depend on how the machines are set up and dotfiles are deployed. There's nothing about it in the question so I'll have to guess a little.

You can write `distro.vim` e.g. from a shell script much like that in the question or a makefile when you set up a new machine and install your dotfiles. A less favorable option would be to write it from a shell profile whenever you log in.

Also, the configuration should be ignored in whatever tool is used to setup the dotfiles, e.g. add it to `.gitignore` if Git is what you use.

Main advantages of this approach:

- easy to adapt to allow for other distinguishing features other than Linux distro.
- equally easy to expand or make exceptions. You can script something or just edit that file.
- uses both shell script and Vim for what they're good at.
- comes with the minimal performance penalty of `source`ing another file and re-setting some options. You should not be able to notice.

Comment: Good idea. It would be much more flexible to write the file as a heredoc.

Comment: you can even use `$ENV` variables to make it more flexible. And heredocs could also be used if you really want to

Comment: I'd use whatever integrates nicest with the deployment strategy. There's nothing of it in the question so we can only guess.

Comment: I like this answer much. I tend to split also my dotfiles in a generic one plus a specific (per host currently but that's not always the right way to go) Final organisation depends the deployment tools

Answer (score 2):

I would do:

```vimscript
let distrib = system('source /etc/os-release && typeset -p ID')
if distrib =~ '(rhel|fedora.*|amzn|ol|rocky|almalinux)'
  " ...
endif
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it doesn't seem to work for me. Have you tested it?

Comment: I tested it on WSL Ubuntu. I could provide a more robust version but the idea is to use `system` to get the output of `source`

Answer (score 2):

Here's my version:

```
:echo readfile('/etc/os-release')->filter({k,v -> v =~# '^ID='})[0]->slice(3)
```

This errors if `!filereadable('/etc/os-release')` and assumes the line of interest is exactly `ID=<value>`. If the file *must* be interpreted by a shell to be correct, something like [Vivian's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/43352/10604) using `source` in `systemlist()` is probably more appropriate.

Comment: This is nice, but it errors in `nvim`, which I also use. `E117: Unknown function: slice`

Comment: Must be new. You can technically accomplish something similar with `[3:]` or similar syntax @paradroid

Answer (score 1):

Will this work ?

```
function! GetLinuxDistro()
    let os_release_path = '/etc/os-release'
    
    if filereadable(os_release_path)
        let os_info = readfile(os_release_path)
        for line in os_info
            if line =~ 'PRETTY_NAME'
                return substitute(line, 'PRETTY_NAME="\(.*\)"', '\1', '')
            endif
        endfor
    endif
    
    return 'Unknown Linux Distribution'
endfunction

echo GetLinuxDistro()
```

Comment: Welcome to Vi and Vim SE and thank you for writing an answer. Most great answers explain how and why they solve a problem. You could [edit] your answer and tell us what your function does.

Comment: yes, should work

Answer (score 0):

> I've started using different terminal colours on different machines/servers to help me know where I am and wanted to change the vim colourschemes to match. I can't think of a better way to differentiate as they all use the same dotfiles. I could use hostnames, but this would not need updating.

Or you could:

- make sure all your shells expose an appropriate `$TERM`, like `xterm-16color`,
- and use a 16color-ready colorscheme in Vim, like `default` and any of the other built-in ones or [this one](https://github.com/romainl/Apprentice) or [that one](https://github.com/romainl/vim-malotru).

That way, Vim doesn't need to be aware of where it is running; it always shows the expected colors.

Comment: I have ssh forwarding `$TERM` fine and all shells local and remote are either `xterm-256` or `tmux-256color` with 16m Truecolor and everything displaying as it should (with this fix http://ix.io/4JPR). In tmux things aren't quite perfect, but only if I look very closely. Not sure what you mean, as I basically want different colours on remote servers compared to local machines, as it helps workflow, remembering where I am in the terminal.) It's `$LS_COLORS` and vim colorschemes that I am conditionally changing, I should have been clearer.)

Comment: I suspect what paradroid is saying is that they _want_ each machine to use different colors. Not my thing, but it could be an interesting way to quickly distinguish things if working on multiple machines regularly.

Comment: Misunderstanding on my part: I thought the whole terminal palette was different from one machine to another, which would have made adding that logic to Vim superfluous. If all OP did was change their `$LS_COLORS` then my answer is irrelevant. FWIW, a colleague of mine used a similar technique a few years ago: one profile/theme per host, with a different background for each, all set at the terminal emulator level. It seemed to work well for him.

Comment: Ever notice when a ~100 rep user writes an answer that's slightly besides the point, they get 3 downvotes and death threats in the comments. Do the same at 38k rep and OP apologizes for having asked the wrong question :D

Comment: That's why we rake those internet points in. They give us insane POWERS and shield us from scrutiny and responsibility.